# R cleaning, change data format horizontal to vertical, repeating some data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

Right now, my data looks like this:

```
Coder Bill Witness1name Witness1job Witness2name Witness2Job

Joe    123    Fred        Plumber       Bob         Coach
Karen  122    Sally       Barista       Helen       Translator
Harry  431    Lisa        Swimmer       N/A         N/A
Frank  301    N/A         N/A           N/A         N/A
```

But I want my data to look like this:

```
Coder    Bill   WitnessName   WitnessJob

Joe       123    Fred          Plumber
Joe       123    Bob           Coach
Karen     122    Sally         Barista
Karen     122    Helen         Translator
Harry     431    Lisa          Swimmer
Frank     301    N/A           N/A
```

So I want to take it from the coder/bill level to the "witness" level. Some coder/bills have up to 10 witnesses in their rows. Some have no witnesses, but I do not want to completely drop them from the dataset (see Frank).

All help is appreciated! I am familiar with the tidyverse package.

Comment: Look  for tidyr::pivot_longer function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61367186/pivot-longer-into-multiple-columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pivot\_longer into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61367186/pivot-longer-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I figured it out.
I had to change all the column names like this:
Witness1Name to Witness1_Name
Witness1Job to Witness1_Job
etc.

Then I ran this:

```
cleandata <- pivot_longer(mddata, cols = -c(Coder, Bill), 
                    names_to = c("Witness", ".value"),
                    names_pattern = 'Witness(\\d)_(.*)') %>%
  drop_na(Name)
```

And it gave me this:

```
Coder    Bill    Witness   Name         Job

Joe       123       1       Fred          Plumber
Joe       123       2       Bob           Coach
Karen     122       1       Sally         Barista
Karen     122       2      Helen         Translator
Harry     431       1       Lisa          Swimmer
```

Close enough to what I wanted