Rearranging dataset for graphing two y variables in R
I am trying to rearrange a dataset to create a line graph with two y-variables that will use the same scale, meaning that there will only be one y-axis. One of my variables has significantly higher values than the other so I am hoping to create a broken y-axis.
I think the first step to being able to graph this data set is rearranging my table to go from this:
Current format: (https://i.sstatic.net/pzHHRyUf.png)
To something like this:
Desired format: (https://i.sstatic.net/y2YH6e0w.png)
I am pretty new to R so I am not sure how to do this. Can anyone provide some guidance?
Thanks!

Perform a search here for "pivot_longer" in the dplyr package.  That will allow you to reshape the data. Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61367186/pivot-longer-into-multiple-columns/61369721#61369721.  The broken y axis is a different question.

I like to use tidyr::pivot_longer() for this task. Here's a chapter on reshaping data like you're describing. https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html

@Dave2e I think you meant to say in the tidyr package, or in the tidyverse meta-package that includes both tidyr and dplyr.

Thanks Jon! That chapter was super helpful and I was able to successfully rearrange my table.
